# why we need js library like json2 to process json?

Tags: javascript

I think javascript can handle json directly, why we need library like json2?

```
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Because it's not supported in older IE versions. It's part of ES5.

Comment: because not all browsers implement the JSON methods.

Comment: [downvoting because this question shows a distinct lack of research](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Answer (score 8):

Because some browsers don't have the JSON object that allows you to parse and stringify json

Answer (score 5):

It's a more recent addition to browser support. See the matrix here of which browsers support it:
http://caniuse.com/json

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 3.1+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, and Opera 10.5+ support native JSON parsing.

For all other browser say IE6 if you want to parse JSON, you have to use this kind of library.

Answer (score 0):

For older browser support, i.e. it is a "shim" or a "[polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill)", of course newer browsers have native JSON support.

If you are converting a JSON string to a Javascript object, then you don't require it, you can just do

`var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");`

Note this argument

> eval is evil
>
> The eval function (and its relatives, Function, setTimeout, and
>   setInterval) provide access to the JavaScript compiler. This is
>   sometimes necessary, but in most cases it indicates the presence of
>   extremely bad coding. The eval function is the most misused feature of
>   JavaScript.

But the library has a method for you to convert from a Javascript object to JSON string, and it performs other checks and adds a little safety around ´eval´ etc